# How to resize header on scroll pixel by pixel

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, react-hooks

I have a navbar header that I am resizing its height according to the scroll(resize pixel by pixel, max 100px and min 56px). I tried to set the state  on scroll but scrolling speed is always happening faster than the speed of calculating and updating the state which result in wrong new values.

resulting into a mess like this

scolled faster
[image]

scrolled slowly
[image]

An idea to stop the lag or a better implementation is highly appreciated.

[The error free header I need](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=error%20free&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

[What I have so far](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-wiles-g27zl?file=/src/header.js)

```
  const [newHeader, setCount] = useState(100);
    const classes = useStyles();
    useEffect(() => {
      window.onscroll = function () {
        var pixel = window.scrollY;
        setCount(100 - pixel)
        // var newHeader = 100 - pixel;

    if (newHeader > 56) {
        document.getElementById('header_container').setAttribute("style", "height:" + newHeader + "px");
       }
     }
 });
```

Comment: I think that you need yo work with font size, if you want to change the header size container you need to add height and width

Comment: Other side you can add a multiplier for each scroll, for example pixel/10

Comment: I am not really sure about what you mean by multiplier, could you please write a small script and push it as an answer @JuanCaicedo you'd be a life saver

Comment: pixel divide by 100, or pixel *0.01

Comment: I am not sure if I wrote the question wrong but, I am trying to shrink the Header navbar the same pixels that I scrolled, so far It works but there is this inconsistency at updating the header's height values when you scroll faster @JuanCaicedo and that is the issue I am trying to fix.

Comment: I think that if you add a min and max value when the value is less than or greater than it will fix your inconsistency

Comment: add this and now the header became fixed(it's not shrinking anymore) ` `style`, `min-height: 56px; max-height: 100px; height: ${newHeader} px` ` @JuanCaicedo

Comment: cool, it works!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215796/discussion-between-bihire-boris-and-juan-caicedo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set max and min limits.

Try this.

```js
    window.onscroll = function() {
      const maxHeight = 100;
      const minHeight = 56;
      let pixel = window.scrollY;
      let pixelPosition =  maxHeight - pixel;
      pixelPosition = pixelPosition > maxHeight ? maxHeight : pixelPosition;
      pixelPosition = pixelPosition < minHeight ? minHeight : pixelPosition;
      document
        .getElementById("header_container")
        .setAttribute("style", "height:" + pixelPosition + "px");
    };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot fam, +1 you saved my day